# Google TV targetSdkVersion 14

Tags: google-play, google-tv

I made an update to my app and among other things I set my targetSdkVersion to 14. Now, my app does not appear in the Google TV Market (note that it used to appear before the update).

Any ideas why this might happen?

PS: 1) I know about the "uses touchscreen required=false" tag, so it's not that.
2) I started using the Action Bar Sherlock in this update, but it seems unlikely that this is the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google TV is currently at SDK=12

Comment: so if I set my targetSdkVersion to 14 will it should show up right?

Comment: and MinSDK to at 12 or lower.

Comment: this comment is the answer: "No official support for native code on GoogleTV"

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. It wasn't the sdk version. It is because of native code currently only built for arm, and google tv runs x86.

Comment: so, how can I have my app not get filtered on that Market?

Comment: also I think your answer is better, so can you post as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

The google tv SDK current version is 3.1 honeycomb(12)

U can set a SDK version to 12 in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />
```

above this command ur app will run 12 and above SDK version

and this command will set ur app to 12 SDK version and it will not run above 12 are belove 12 SDK version

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="12" />
```

i hope this help u